# MYSQL: Weekly , Monthly and Yearly Report

Tags: mysql

i want to make report that can be viewed by weekly , monthly and yearly.

for example:
i want to see who enrolled by weekly , or i want to see who enrolled in this month or year and also about the payments. i want to see the enrollee this june . i want to see the enrollee this 2010 by using a dropdown search.

// this is my code for my weekly report which i want to see students who enrolled last week but i dnt know if my code is correct.

```
$datetoday=date("Y-m-d");
$result = mysql_query("
     SELECT enrollee_info.*, payments.* from enrollee_info 
 INNER JOIN payments on payments.enrollee_id=enrollee_info.e_id 
      WHERE enrollee_info.category='Walk In' 
       AND DATE_FORMAT(payments.entrydate , %Y-%m-d')>=SUBDATE('".$datetoday."' , INTERVAL 7 DAY)");
```

with monthly and yearly , for example i want to see who enrolled this month etc. and i want to see who enrolled this year by using a dropdown that you can select month or the year you want to search.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Why not use `CURDATE()` instead of `$datetoday`? If `payments.entrydate` is a `date` type, there is no need to use `DATE_FORMAT`

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk , for you i'll try that .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) regarding the acceptable units for `INTERVAL`. You can simply use a switch to determine the range for your records.

In your drop down you'll have week, month or year. You can then use a switch to prepare your statement.

```
$sql = "SELECT enrollee_info.*, 
   payments.* 
FROM   enrollee_info 
       INNER JOIN payments 
               ON payments.enrollee_id = enrollee_info.e_id 
WHERE  enrollee_info.category = 'Walk In' 
       AND payments.entrydate >= Subdate(Curdate(), ";

switch ($range) {
    case "month":
        $sql .= 'INTERVAL 1 MONTH';
        break;
    case "year":
        $sql .= 'INTERVAL 1 YEAR';
        break;
    //if no match, use week
    default:
        $sql .= 'INTERVAL 1 WEEK';
}

$sql .= ')';
```

Which would create a statement like this:

```
SELECT enrollee_info.*, 
       payments.* 
FROM   enrollee_info 
       INNER JOIN payments 
               ON payments.enrollee_id = enrollee_info.e_id 
WHERE  enrollee_info.category = 'Walk In' 
       AND payments.entrydate >= Subdate(Curdate(), INTERVAL 1 week)
```

If possible, try to avoid fetching all columns from each table and use a column list.

Comment: Could you please help me on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083549/order-query-according-to-clause